# Select whole content, not whole block in sublime vintage mode

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

Is there an easy way to select the whole content of a line? I always use `V` to select the whole block, but it brings me a lot of problems in some cases, so I need to go to the start of the content with `^`, press `v` + `$` to select and go to the end of content, that is a lot to do. I was thinking about a macro but maybe there is a native way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any native way; I use this in my `.vimrc`:

```
onoremap ii :<c-u>normal! v^og_<cr>
xnoremap ii ^og_
```

Comment: Nice, could you or someone else translate it to a sublime text keybind? I don't really understand these commands as I rarely use actual vim for programming. But I'll try to make a macro myself based on the logic, thanks :)